# How can I size an image background to text in PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to create a background for some varying text in PIL. I want the width to remain the same, but I want to be able to scale the height depending on the amount of wrapped text (i.e. stretching to fit the text).
Is this possible?

Comment: do you really mean stretching or you want it to repeat (maybe with borders)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.